# Toast like Android in Dart Application with angular2js

Tags: javascript, dart, angular, angular-dart

There is an official dart package written in angular2js to reproduce a Toast Message like an Android Application?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about Dart actually but yes there is one library for toast like android in angular2 here is code exmaple for the same.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app', 
    template: `
      <button (click)="displayToastr()">Display Toastr</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  displayToastr() {
    toastr.info('I am here for few seconds');
  }
}
```

here is [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qb2YpJhd6V0JOBAK12kO?p=preview) for the same. may gives you hint.

Comment: Does Android platform use javascripts?

Comment: i don't know but this question is not related to android i think its about like android not in android is't it ?

Comment: in dart doesn't exist. I fount this: https://github.com/jeffmoss/toastd. a use yaml dependencies: toastd: any but in pub get i'll take ackage toastd depends on unittest from unknown source "sdk".